# When is a day in SE over?

Tags: discussion

I had a 200 rep day and I'm wondering when the clock get's reset in here.

Based upon my observations regarding resetting the voting clock it doesn't seem to happen from the last vote.  That the clock is reset on a fixed time in the code seems to me how the time function works.

But those are votes and perhaps a different mechanism.

Does anyone know when and how the time clock is reset for reputation once hit the max?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you implying you can't get more than 200 rep. a day?

Comment: Has anyone else spotted the amusing typo in this question?

Comment: There's a few of them.  Which one?   :-)      AND...correct, you cannot exceed 200 rep in a day.   There are various badges related to getting 200 rep in a day as well.  bronze 1st time,  silver 50 times, and gold 200 times.

Comment: clock not cock, and I think gold is 200 rep. 150 times if I'm not mistaken

Comment: lol....good eye max....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything here is based on UTC, and things (like the 200 reputation cap) roll over at midnight UTC (00:00, which comes directly after 23:59). You can see the current UTC time in the achievements dropdown:

[image]